# TimeZone proplem in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Table name like users following columns are there

```
*Id -------------- (int type)
*DateandTime --------(Date type)
*Name -------------(varchar type)

I already insert one row like

Id = 123
Name = MR.X
DateandTime = 2018-01-12 06:22:06
```

Now select query in sequelize

```
model.user.findAll({
   attributes: ['ID','DateandTime','NAME'],
   where: {ID: useId} })
.then((userResult) => {
....... })
```

but getting **DateandTime** "2018-01-12T06:22:06.000Z"

Answer (score 1):

You are getting out exactly what you put in. You have inserted a row as a string and it has been converted to a UTC date, it has not been stored the same as the string you put in.

When requesting it back out again, it is returning the date you put in, but from its database date form, not the original string.

You need to either store the date string as a string (varchar) if you just want the value as-is. Or, if you need to use the date for any date related functions, when you retrieve it back to display, you need to convert it to the string value you want.

I suggest using moment.js

```
const stringDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
```